# Update column based on where group by having count = 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to update a blank column with either a PledgeId or anything to populate the new column I've created to update.

I want to update the field. I have tried numerous different ways to update the field.

The code I am using that narrows what I am looking for, but can't seem to update the field with it due to different errors:

```
select IDPledge
from PledgePaymentSchedule
where DatePaid != ''
group by IDPledge
having count(IDPledge) = 1
```

I am looking for specific records that have a `DatePaid` that is not blank, grouped by `IDPledge`, having a count of exactly one. Meaning a *one time* Pledge.

The most recent variant of many different tries:

```
Update [PledgePaymentSchedule] 
set [OneTimePledge] = 'Yes'
where exists
(SELECT count([IDPledge]) FROM [PledgePaymentSchedule]
where [DatePaid] !=  ''
group by [IDPledge]
having count([IDPledge]) = 1)
```

This updates all records with 'Yes' instead of just the 26 records that pull from the where exists statement.

---

```
Update s
set [OneTimePledge] = (SELECT distinct count(*)         FROM [PledgePaymentSchedule]
group by [IDPledge]
having count([IDPledge]) > 1)
FROM [PledgePaymentSchedule] s
where [DatePaid] !=  ''
```

This variance throws error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
> The statement has been terminated.

Ultimately I need an update statement, that updates column [OneTimePledge] with the results of the select statement at the top.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. You say "due to different errors" - please always post the exact errors you are encountering - we can't read your mind. 2. Please ensure you provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results in addition to your attempt. We need to know what you ultimate goal is.

Comment: You say *due to different errors*: What errors exactly? Could it be that the "blank" `DatePaid` is actually `null` and not the blank string? If so, use `DatePaid is not null`

Comment: Updated my original post. DatePaid is blank when there is no date. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't unnecessarily decorate your code with square brackets, [because] [it] [does] [nothing] [except] [make] [your] [code] [harder] [to] [read].

Comment: It was copied from an in house tool. I can delete the brackets if it bothers you Bohemian. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got this correctly, you want to create a flag indicating that some IDPledge has one (and only one) valid DatePaid value.

It that's the case, I'd suggest working with Common Table Expressions (CTEs) to help you build your update statement:

```
WITH
UpdateJoin AS
(
    SELECT
        OneTimePledge
    FROM
        PledgePaymentSchedule
    WHERE
        IDPledge IN
        (
            select IDPledge
            from PledgePaymentSchedule
            where DatePaid != ''
            group by IDPledge
            having count(IDPledge) = 1
        )
)
UPDATE
    UpdateJoin
SET
    OneTimePledge = 'Yes';
```

Isolating the rows you want to update with CTEs usually helps.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!! I have messed with temp tables before but looks like I'll need to dive back in.

Comment: Anytime! A reminder though... common table expressions only exist for the duration of the code execution. Enjoy (and mark the answer as the solution if the code works for you, please)!